# Button @Onclick only refreshes on first click on the second attempt it now works why?

Tags: web-applications, blazor

I have created a simple login page in Blazor with the following code:

```
@using BananaTailWind.Components.Layout
@using BananaTailWind.Data
@using BananaTailWind.Models
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject Auth authservice
@inject ILogger<LoginLayout> logger
@layout LoginLayout
@page "/"
@page "/Login"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<section class="bg-gray-900 dark:bg-gray-900">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-6 py-8 mx-auto md:h-screen lg:py-0">

        <a href="#" class="flex items-center mb-6 text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900 text-white">
            <img class="w-8 h-8 mr-2" src="images/banana.svg" alt="logo" />
            Macarona Farms
        </a>

        <div class="w-full bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:border md:mt-0 sm:max-w-md xl:p-0 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
            <div class="p-6 space-y-4 md:space-y-6 sm:p-8">
                <h1 class="text-xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-2xl dark:text-white">
                    Sign in to your account
                </h1>
                <form class="space-y-4 md:space-y-6" action="#">

                    <div>
                        <label for="username" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Username</label>
                        <input type="username" name="username" id="username" 
                            class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 
                                    focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" 
                            required="" @bind="Username">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label for="password" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" 
                            class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 
                            dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                            required="" @bind="Password">
                    </div>

                    <button
                            class="w-full text-white bg-primary-600 hover:bg-primary-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center 
                            dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800"
                            @onclick="CheckValidation">
                        Sign in
                    </button>

                    @if (ShowError == true)
                    {
                        <p>Invalid Username and Password</p>
                    }

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
@code {
    protected string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    protected string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    protected bool ShowError { get; set; } = false;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }


    private async Task CheckValidation(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (await authservice.authenticate(Username, Password))
            {
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Home",true);
                StateHasChanged();

            }
            else
            {
                ShowError = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Validation method error: {ex.Message}");

        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to click the button, it only refreshes the page. During the second attempt, it works as expected. Additionally, the Console.WriteLine statement does not display anything in the browser console.

What could be causing this behavior, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at the beginning of CheckValidation? Does the breakpoint get hit each time you click the button?

Comment: Good day yes it hits everytime i click just the first click upon launching the app it wont execute but 2nd attempt works

Comment: And auth service.authenticate returns true the first time you click the button? I don't think you need a StateHasChanged call after you navigate. You haven't changed the values of any variables that would warrant a re-render of the login page. I suspect that if the authenticate method returns true, you just want to navigate to home. By running the StateHasChanged method, you are telling Blazor that you want the page to re-render.

Comment: I'm also not clear why you have 2 @page attributes for this page. You want people to get to this page if they navigate to /Login or /. Not sure why. I assume you have another page with a page attribute with /home. What are you trying to do? Do you want people to be forced to go to your login page if they are not logged in?